# How to show password reset link in response

Tags: php, laravel

I have the code below which sends the password reset link and it works fine. What I want to do is show password reset link or token in response. (Yes, I know it's dangerous.)

```php
        $status = Password::sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email'),
            function ($user, $token) {
                (\DB::table('password_resets')
                    ->updateOrInsert(
                        ['email' => $user->email],
                        [
                            'token' => md5($token)
                        ]
                    ))
                    ? $user->sendPasswordResetNotification(md5($token))
                    : null;
            }

        );

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            if ($status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
                return response()->json(['message' => __($status)], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['message' => __($status)], 422);
            }
        }

        return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
            ? back()->with(['status' => __($status)])
            : back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
    }
```

I changed the code as below but I am getting `500 Internal Server Error`. What's wrong?

```php
        $status = Password::sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email'),
            function ($user, $token) use (&$token) {
                (\DB::table('password_resets')
                    ->updateOrInsert(
                        ['email' => $user->email],
                        [
                            'token' => md5($token)
                        ]
                    ))
                    ? $user->sendPasswordResetNotification(md5($token))
                    : null;
            }

        );

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            if ($status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
                return response()->json(['message' => __($status), 'link' => md5($token)], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json(['message' => __($status)], 422);
            }
        }

        return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
            ? back()->with(['status' => __($status)])
            : back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be like this:

```
$token = DB::table('password_resets')->latest('created_at')->first()->token;
```

You get the last record inserted in the table (by sorting `created_at` column) which is the latest password reset and you can get the token from that.

```
return response()->json(['message' => __($status), 'link' => $token], 200);
```

And you getting the `500 Server Error` could be from the addition of `use (&$token)` in the second code. `use` is the way to use the variables out of the function scope in the function and you don't have any variable named `$token` (Don't confuse with the `$token` in the function). And you're using the `use` to use a function variable outside of its scope which won't work.
Also you could set `APP_DEBUG` to true (NOT IN PRODUCTION MODE) to see the reason for 500 error.